# Add two times of different format in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, php-5.3

In my table, I have a variable `$duration` which is stored in minutes.
And I also have a time variable. Let it be `$time1`.

```
$time1=date('H:i:s',$time);


$duration=1000; //minutes
$time2= secondsToTime($duration*60);
```

I convert the `$duration` to time format using the function given below.

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h:%i:%s');
}
```

- So in `$time2`, i have something like this stored `11:12:13`
- And in `$time1` i have something like this stored `01:10:19`

I want to perform `$total=$time1+$time2;`

So, I converted `$time2` into time format.

```
$timeform= new DateTime($time2); 
$newtime2= $timeform->format('H:i:s');
```

Now, I add `$total=$time1+$newtime2;`

But `echo date('H:i:s',$total);`gave me following error:

> Notice: Object of class `DateTime` could not be converted to `int`

Comment: I expect I'd use PHP function dateTime add OR convert each to seconds, add, and convert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `date()` should be a timestamp (i.e. an integer, i.e. seconds), not a formatted date string.

As far as I know only comparison operators work on datetime objects (`$date1 > $date2`), not math operators (`$date1 + $date2`).

See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

- Use 1 datetime instance for calculating/formatting the total amount of time
- Or, convert 2 datetime instances to seconds, add them, and format using `date()`

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `date()` is expected to be a Unix timestamp as integer, not a `DateTime` object. (see [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php))

You need to convert your `DateTime` object into a Unix timestamp.

Try [`getTimestamp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php):

```
echo date('H:i:s',$total->getTimestamp());
```